# UnsaturatedTypeFamilies in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Does any version of GHC supports the extension `UnsaturatedTypeFamilies` ?

Searching [9.2.1 manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/search.html?q=UnsaturatedTypeFamilies&check_keywords=yes&area=default) shows no entry

In general, how to find which GHC version supports an extension ?

Comment: I don't think it's been implemented, yet, at least in releases. I can only find it mentioned in proposals. https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0242-unsaturated-type-families.rst

Comment: @chi oh no I thought it *was* on the release horizon for some reason (beyond the proposal).. too bad.. I wonder what's the status. if its like impredicative or deterministic build this will never happen in my lifetime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/242).

While the proposal for this feature has been accepted as an experimental feature for inclusion in GHC, there is currently no official released version of GHC that supports this extension, and there is no development branch in the main GHC GitLab repository that includes it, as far as I can see.  A prototype by Csongor Kiss who authored the [proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0242-unsaturated-type-families.rst) is available from Csongor's private repository branch:

> https://gitlab.haskell.org/kcsongor/ghc/tree/master

and that appears to be the latest available implementation.